# MySQL 5.1.73 to 5.6.17 structure + data export

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Are there any known issues to export structure and data from MySQL 5.1.73 to 5.6.17? Nothing fancy and to export-import user will use phpMyAdmin.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be [binary compatible](http://www.percona.com/blog/2010/01/05/upgrading-mysql/), but I would **ALWAYS** use mysqldump. See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13122/why-is-my-mysql-dump-file-and-my-phpmyadmin-export-file-different-sizes) (options not always optimal) and [here](http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/mysql-database-backup-restore-phpmyadmin.php) (phpMyAdmin can't handle large dbs) for why. See [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75777/how-can-i-move-a-mysql-database-from-5-1-to-5-6/75791#75791) and [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/move-mysql-users-privileges-grants-from-one-host-to-new-host.html) for how. And let's not forget the [docco](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/copying-databases.html)!

Comment: Thanks! Not sure if GoDady has access to a terminal to do mysqldump, but I will double check that.

Comment: Thanks for the correct answer! I put in a reference to binary compatibility also. As for Godaddy - it [depends](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/4978/connecting-remotely-to-shared-hosting-databases?countrysite=ie) on your plan.