# Importing Data with Single .ibd file

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, mysql-5

I have one ".ibd" file with me. I have configured my local Database server with FILE_PER_TABLE option. i have two question here.

1. When i was trying to restore/import the IBD file, the engine expect me to have the structure information. Is it not possible to load the data and structure using Single IBD file?
2. Also can we do hot copy and restore the innodb files from one server to other as MyISAM engine?

Please need your suggestion on the same.

Comment: You can't copy the ibd files to another MySQL instance without some hackery because the metadata in the ibd file won't match what's in the global InnoDB data dictionary. Instead you can use one of the methods that Vérace describes.

Answer (score 1):

1) To get a single table restored and/or imported, use mysqldump. See the "how" links in my post [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75813/mysql-5-1-73-to-5-6-17-structure-data-export/75817?noredirect=1#comment137228_75817).

2) For a hot copy of InnoDB tables, use Perconas [XtraBackup](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup) tool (BTW, the Percona website generally and their mysqlperformance [blog](http://www.percona.com/blog/) are excellent MySQL resources).

You can also [replicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-and-mysql-replication.html) from InnoDB masters to MyISAM slaves and the other way round (although why one would want to do this is a mystery to me).